# Retrieving email in html format with cron

Tags: php, html, cron

Hello fellow citizens of ....oh skip all that... I am experiencing some difficulty trying to output html via my cron and I have checked other responses to this issue.  But, I can’t seem to get it right so I’m hoping someone out there can assist me.  The data pulls correctly and the cron email sends but what I end up with is my data with all the html tags appended.  I have tried moving the $to and $header out of the while loop, above the while loop, below the while loop, and also tried with everything inside the while loop with only the $message being the one call to dtat $row etc and then echo'd that from within the loop.
I have tried two versions of ---

```
( $headers .= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' 
. "\r\n";)
```

and

```
( $headers .= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8-1' . 
"\r\n";)
```

So any assistance would be great!
Cheers!

```
$db = new MySQLi('------', '------', '------', '------');

if ($db->connect_error)  {
    $mese = $db->connect_error;   } else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $to = "some@gmail.com";
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859- 
            1'
            . "\r\n";

        $message = "<html>";
        $message .= "<head></head>";
        $message .= "<body>";
        $message .= '<ul><li>' . $row['item'] .'</li></ul>';
        echo $message;
        $message .= "</body>";
        $message = "</html>";

        $from = "somewhere@.someplace.net";    $subject = "checking php
     mail";

        mail($headers, $to,$subject,$message, $from);

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: btw:The data works and email sends and recieves, the problem I am trying to solve is getting the text to output as html and not plain text. cheers

Comment: Drop the -1 on the utf: `text/html;charset=utf-8`

Comment: Just did that 'dropped -1 it didn't work

Comment: Check the headers of the received email, so if there's any clue there as to what's going on. Check the content-type there.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised it's sending at all. Headers should be at the end with the from, not the beginning. `mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, mixed $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`

Comment: Hi aynbar so should I move my header down just outside of the while loop ? I will check headers of recieved mail, thanks.

Comment: No, you need to add the headers towards the end of the function. `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` Your `$from` needs to be merged into the `$headers`.

Comment: ok placing at bottom of function

Comment: Your $from needs to be merged into the $headers?  Could you elaborate?

Comment: `$headers .= "From: somewhere@.someplace.net\r\n";`. It shouldn't be passed separately into the mail function.

Comment: Hi I placed headers at bottom inside of while loop....no change.

Comment: Where it is in the loop doesn't matter. What matters is where it is when you call the mail function. See my comment above for the order.

Comment: Ok trying that thanks!

Comment: ok well I have placed the headers just above the mail function inside the while loop and corrected the from issue still recieved plain text.

Comment: wait moving headers variable to the end of mail function list

Comment: Merged the from into the headers and relocated the headers variable at the end inside the mail fnction call list then recieved one blank email for each row of data in my while loop. Moved header to first spot in mail()function and now recieve email with the data list and plain html again.

Comment: Also notice the email is being recieved directly from the crondaemon at my hosting company.  Ill look into that, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

All the quotes in your code are messed up. This could be the reason.

Try this:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message =  '<html>';
$message .= '<head></head>';
$message .= '<body>';
$message .= '<ul><li>' . $row['item'] .'</li></ul>';
$message .= '</body>';
$message .= '</html>';
```

Comment: Hi I gave it a go too with the reordered quotes and no echo/ no email recieved.  Then tried the reordered quotes as you suggested with the original echo in place and the email recieves with plain text still.